# UIViewController with background image

Tags: iphone, ipad, uiviewcontroller, background-image

How can I insert into my UIViewController an image from the resources as background image?
thanks in advance!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Add it `UIViewController`'s view, somewhat like this:

```
- (void) viewDidLoad 
{
   UIImage *background = [UIImage imageNamed: @"background.png"];    
   UIImageView *imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage: background]; 

   [self.view addSubview: imageView]; 

   [imageView release];

   [super viewDidLoad];
}
```

Comment: I see about 10px margin at the top.  Is there something that I'm missing?

Comment: @vishalashah Try setting the frame of your imageview to that of your viewcontroller's view, prior to adding it as its subview.

Comment: For a background view you probably want to use `[self.view insertSubview: imageView atIndex:0];` otherwise it will be on top of your other xib stuff.

Comment: There's no need to add an image view to do so, it will make the view controller slow to load. Simply, in the storyboard change the background of the view to any color and then in the `viewDidLoad` add `[[self view] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]]];` it'll make it better and will look great even if you scroll.

Answer (score 8):

UIViewControllers don't have background images. Only views themselves have visual attributes.

UIView does not have a background image property. To display a background image, you usually simply put a UIImageView displaying the image in the view hierarchy so that it appears visually behind all other views. This can be done programmatically or in Interface Builder.

Comment: Thanks you, I've looked at numerous posts regarding background image and tried all sorts of code that didn't work, it seems with Storyboards this is the best way to accomplish.  Thanks.