# Set background image in UIViewController (MonoTouch)

Tags: iphone, uiviewcontroller, xamarin.ios, monodevelop

I have a screen called HomeScreen which implements UIViewController.  I wish to use a background image for this screen.  Is there an event that I can override to set this background image in the HomeScreen.cs file?

Comment: UIVIewController doesnt quite have a BackgroundView / Image member, you have to create a UImageView and then addSubView Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2991040/uiviewcontroller-with-background-image

Comment: Thanks.  This isn't a dup though, since my question was MonoTouch-related.

Comment: However, if you can show your suggestion in MonoTouch, I'd love to see it.  Sounds like it is my best bet.  Thanks!

Comment: I figured it out... within the ViewDidLoad put... this.View.AddSubview(new UIImageView(UIImage.FromFile(@"Images/Background-home@2x.png")));

Comment: @Anuj - I've added a SubView, but now I can't see my buttons that I originally had in my view.  I can guess where they are and click them, but I cannot see them.

Comment: they are likely under the UIImageView. I would addSubView on the UImageView before adding the UIButtons and let me know how that goes. Feel free to throw up a gist so we have a better picture of what exactly is going on as well :-)

Comment: Instead of adding the image view with AddSubview, use InsertSubview: this.View.InsertSubview(imageView, 0); - this will add the image view and make it the first subview (=behind everything else) of the View.

Answer (score 13):

try setting the BackgroundColor of your View

```
myview.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("myimage.png"));
```

Comment: is there any way to make the image scale to the view size and still using it as a background color?

Comment: @nhenrique I am wondering this as well, did you find a solution?

Comment: @nhenrique I've added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618726/4332059) for your question

Comment: @ElliotBlackburn I've added a [new answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47618726/4332059) to solve the different sizes IPhone problem

Comment: @OldFox wow this is old, thanks for updating it. Hopefully it'll help someone else in the future. I don't even use Xamarin anymore haha

Answer (score 4):

I voted up for the other answers, however today IPhone has different sizes and the correct way to load the image is using [`UIImage.FromBundle`](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/working_with_images/displaying-an-image/#Displaying_an_Image_in_Code) method:

Here is the assert catalog in the project:

[image]

To manage the images:

[image]

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();

    // replace "name" with the desired name in the asset catalog
    this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromBundle("name"));

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try adding something like the following to your MyViewNameViewController.cs:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    this.View.BackgroundColor = UIColor.FromPatternImage(UIImage.FromFile("splash.png"));
}
```